What's the best way to safely separate the Linux operating system from the Windows operating system on a single physical disk?
I currently have a new laptop with one SSD drive empty. I'm going to install Linux and Windows on it via dualboot. Linux for work and Windows for gaming. How do I make sure that no virus can get from Windows to Linux?
But without encrypting the logical disk where Linux is installed.

Generally, normal drive partitioning prevents most common malware attacks, as Windows cannot natively "understand" the Linux drive format, and Linux will not have the Windows partition mounted. What methods have you already investigated? What research have you done and what have you tried?

For absolute security, install each OS in a separate USB SSD. Oops -- even that is not absolute, since LogoFail infects the firmware: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogoFAIL

Malware cannot using the same payload infect both Windows and Linux, that’s simply not possible, using a temporary Linux VM is a good solution. Malware is exceedingly easy to avoid with a small effort

I agree with @Ramhound that the same malware will not impact both operating systems, I don't see a need to run Linux in a temporary VM. Dual boot should be sufficient and there is no need to use a separate SSD for each OS.

@doneal24 - It is extremely simple to script an automated Linux VM configuration deployment. It’s tougher to do that same script deployment with Windows due to a variety of reasons

@Ramhound I'm not seeing any need for an automated deployment of either OS. The OP seems to be asking about a one-time installation on a new laptop. The differences between a Linux install on hardware and on a VM are trivial.
